# Libcurl post request not working on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, libcurl

I am trying to make a simple POST request to my https REST API and receive the response on a Windows 7 operation system. The firewall is deactivated and the certificate is inside the .exe directory.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
std::string postRequest(std::string json, std::string endpoint,std::string code,std::string patchOrPOST,std::string source)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string response;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    std::string authorization = "Authorization: Basic " + code, portApiHttp = "Referer: " + portAPI + "/index.html", origin = "Origin: " + portAPI;//X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    if (curl) {
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Connection: keep-alive");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Length: "+(int)strlen(json.c_str()));
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, authorization.c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        if (source.size() != 0)
        {
            headers = curl_slist_append(headers, source.c_str());
        }
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, R"(sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="91")");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "X - Requested - With: XMLHttpRequest"); 
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, origin.c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, portApiHttp.c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,endpoint.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "ca-bundle.crt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
        if (patchOrPOST == "PATCH")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
        }
        else if (patchOrPOST == "PUT")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        }
        else if (patchOrPOST == "GET")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        }
        else if(patchOrPOST=="DELETE")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
        }
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:8888");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        if (patchOrPOST != "GET")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, json.size());
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        }
        res= curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        if (res!= CURLE_OK) {
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            return "ERROR";
        }
        res= curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
        if (res!= CURLE_OK) {
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            return "ERROR";
        }
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        long http_code;
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return response;
}
```

Why does this code work on Windows 10, but has SSL issues on Windows 7?

Comment: Sounds more like a network stack configuration problem than something wrong with your code. Use a suitable sniffer like WireShark to investigate what probably goes wrong at that level.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try to gain some information that way!

Comment: did you try checking the curl error code?

Comment: Yes, I used CURLOPT_VERBOSE, but the .exe seems to stop working whenever I have that activated.

Comment: I found out that the error is "shutting down SSL/TSS connection / failed SLL connect error". Why do I only have this issue on the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: `"Content-Length: "+json.size()` This can't be compiled. Few 0 and 1 should be 0L and 1L.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try to see if I can find another way of sending the json length. I also turned of the verification process, but I still get "failed: SSL cannot connect".

Comment: @prestige Please [edit] andupdate this question with the enhanced information you investigated, instead of asking a new one (closed it). Editing your question will bump it up at the home view for everyone.

Comment: `"Content-Length: "+(int)strlen(json.c_str())` - this is wrong. You again perform a pointer arithmetic. For example `"Content-Length: "+7` will pass `"-Length: "`. If `json.size()` is greater than 16, you make a step into the world of Undefined Behavior. I can't imagine how it can work on Windows 10.

Comment: @273K Oh wow thanks, didn't know that. The content-length is still being overwritten by CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, that's why it probably didn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this code work on Windows 10, but has SSL issues on Windows 7?

Most likely, the server is requesting stronger cryptographic suites than what Windows 7 can provide.

Comment: Exactly, this is the issue. I tried changing Windows 7 to TSL 1.2 via regedit, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: To add cipher suites, use the group policy setting SSL Cipher Suite Order under Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > SSL Configuration Settings to configure a priority list for all cipher suites you want enabled.

Comment: Thanks for bringing us a step closer! We have been doing multiple requests to other websites and they all worked, but not with our REST API. We found out that our host only accepts the newest 1.2 cipher suites. I have added "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" to the Windows 7 SSL Cipther Suite Order as you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, unfortunately Windows 7 doesn't support that cipher, which means it won't work, unless we change our host. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with Windows 7 and `libcurl`. I have found a solution. I was using `libcurl` with `schannel` (default for windows when using vcpkg). The problem was solved when I built `libcurl` with `openssl` instead.

If you are using `vcpkg`, you can install `libcurl` with `openssl` with this command:
`vckpg.exe install curl[openssl]`

You can download a precompiled binary from curl site too. I got the hint solve this from this default windows build for curl:

https://github.com/curl/curl-for-win